# How can I stop UITableView from showing searchBar when keyboard hides

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UITableView with a searchBar in the table header. I am calling setContentOffset in viewWillAppear which keeps it hidden at the top.  However whenever the keyboard is displayed and then hidden, say while editing some fields in the detailed view, the searchBar reappears.  Perhaps as a result of default behaviour for the UITableView to adjust itself in response to keyboard events.

Is there any way I can prevent the tableView from scrolling down.  I have tried putting the same setContentOffset in the keyboardDidHide{} but it seems to then offset the tableView by too much.  Ideally I don't want to see any movement in the tableView.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    LOG(@"viewWillAppear: called");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there is a more elegant answer than the one I have come up with.

I am just getting the contentOffset before the keyboard hides itself, getting the searchBar, removing it from the header and then putting it all back once the keyboard has been hidden.  Unfortunately this is not preventing the animation of empty rows but it does stop rows with content from moving down and then back up.

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)n
{
    LOG(@"keyboardWillHide: called");
    _contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    _searchBar = (UISearchBar*)self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
}
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)n
{
    LOG(@"keyboardDidHide: called");
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar;
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:_contentOffset animated:NO];
}
```